# Is the relation R(ABCDE) with set of FD's {AB->CD, AC->BED, D->A} in 3NF?

Tags: database, normalization, 3nf

Is the relation R(ABCDE) with set of FD's {AB->CD, AC->BED, D->A} in 3NF? I doubt it but the notes i am reading say so. Could someone please explain how is this correct? My understanding is that assuming we take AB as key then the attributes B,E & D are dependent on only a part of the key (i.e. A) thereby violating 2NF property.

Comment: How did you derive A->B, A->E, and A->D?

Comment: ^Oh sorry turns out I was incorrect there. B, E & D are dependent on AC and not just A. But in that case which key/s should be taken as primary?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but there's no formal way to identify which key, among several keys, should be called "primary". These days, "primary key" is more a SQL thing than a relational thing.

Comment: Ok. But to show that this relation is in 3NF, we have to rule out the presence of transitive dependencies, right? How could we do so in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, This Relation is in 3NF
Because,
For the given FD set there are total 4 candidate keys which are AB,AC,DB,DC.
And let us suppose we have key AB, then for the given relation, there is no Partial FD and Transitive FD. So the given relation is in 3NF but is is not in BCNF because of D-->A violates the BCNF rule.

Comment: So only E will be considered a non-key attribute and there are no Partial FD and Transitive FD containing E, hence it is in 3NF. Right?

Comment: Partially correct, E is non key attribute but it is not the reason to be this relation in 3NF. AB is a primary key, so there is no dependency like {A-->XYZ or B-->XYZ (these are partial dependency)} and there is no dependency like (non-key att) --> (non-key att) {Transitive dependency} so that we can say, it is in 3NF . I think it should be clear now.